# Read nth line from string

Tags: java, string, filter

i am trying to read 7th line of a string so that i can filter the required text but not getting more.(assuming i have n number of line).

```
class Lastnthchar {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    String alldata ="   FORM"+"\n"+
                    "   to get all data"+"\n"+
                    "   PART A is mandatory"+"\n"+
                    "   enclose all Certificate"+"\n"+
                    "   Certificate No. SFDSFDFS Last updated on 12-Jun-2009"+"\n"+
                    "   Name and address"+"\n"+
                    "   Lisa Lawerence"+"\n"+
                    "   10/3 TOP FLOOR, Street no 22 ,NewYork"+"\n"+
                    "   residence"+"\n"+
                    "   zip-21232"+"\n"+
                    "   C 78,New York"+"\n"+
                    "   US"+"\n"+
                    "   US"+"\n"+
                    "   "+"\n"+
                    "   worldwide";

    String  namerequired = new String ();

    //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(alldata);
    int lineno = 0;
    for(lineno = 0; lineno <alldata.length(); lineno ++)
    {
    //what should i do?
    }
    }

    }
```

so if any solution please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the BufferedReader you could do the following:

```
class Lastnthchar {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String alldata ="   FORM"+"\n"+
                        "   to get all data"+"\n"+
                        "   PART A is mandatory"+"\n"+
                        "   enclose all Certificate"+"\n"+
                        "   Certificate No. SFDSFDFS Last updated on 12-Jun-2009"+"\n"+
                        "   Name and address"+"\n"+
                        "   Lisa Lawerence"+"\n"+
                        "   10/3 TOP FLOOR, Street no 22 ,NewYork"+"\n"+
                        "   residence"+"\n"+
                        "   zip-21232"+"\n"+
                        "   C 78,New York"+"\n"+
                        "   US"+"\n"+
                        "   US"+"\n"+
                        "   "+"\n"+
                        "   worldwide";

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(alldata));

        String namerequired;
        String line;
        int counter = 0;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (counter == 6) {
                namerequired = line;
            }
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

`alldata.length()` will return the length of the string (i.e. number of characters), not the number of lines.

To get the n<sup>th</sup> line you'll need to split the string at the line breaks, e.g. 
`alldata.split("\n")[6]` to get the 7<sup>th</sup> line (provided there are at least 7 lines).
This also assumes you have line breaks (`\n`) in your string and not just carriage returns (`\r`). If you want to split at both individually or in combination, you can change the parameter of `split()` to `"\r\n|\n|\r"`. If you want to skip empty lines, you can split at any sequence of at least one line break or carriage return, e.g. `"[\r\n]+"`.

Example:

```
System.out.println("--- Input:");
String input = "A\nB\rC\n\nD\r\nE";
System.out.println(input);  

System.out.println("--- 4th element, split by \\n:");
System.out.println(input.split("\n")[3]); //3rd element will be "D\r"
System.out.println("--- 4th element, split by \\r\\n|\\n|\\r:");
System.out.println(input.split("\r\n|\n|\r")[3]); //3rd element will be an empty string 
System.out.println("--- 4th element, split by [\\r\\n]+:");
System.out.println(input.split("[\r\n]+")[3]); //3rd element will be "D"
System.out.println("--- END");
```

Output:

```
--- Input:
A
B
C

D
E
--- 4th element, split by \n:
D

--- 4th element, split by \r\n|\n|\r: 

--- 4th element, split by [\r\n]+:
D
--- END
```

Alternatively, if you're reading the text from some stream (e.g. from a file) you can use `BufferedReader#readLine()` and count the lines. Additionally you can initialize the `BufferedReader` with a `FileReader`, `StringReader` etc., depending on where you read the input from.

If you're reading from the console, the `Console` class also has a `readLine()` method.

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach your problem is to check index of "\n" specified amount of times until you find the line you need. I'm writing this off the top of my head so i'm sorry if syntax is not 100% accurate, but the logic is here:

```
public String readSpecifiedLine(String str, int lineNumber){
   int lineStartIndex = 0; 
   //start by finding start of specified line
   for(int i=0;i<lineNumber;i++){
      lineStartIndex = str.IndexOf("\n",lineStartIndex); //find new line symbol from
      //specified index
      lineStartIndex++; //increase the index by 1 so the to skip newLine Symbol on
      //next search or substring method
      //Note, you might need to increase by 2 if "\n" counts as 2 characters in a string
}
int nextLine = str.IndexOf("\n",lineStartIndex); //end of line 7
retrun str.substring(lineStartIndex,nextline);
}
```

You might need to play around with indexes